# Syntax error handling in dojo 18n resource file

Tags: dojo, internationalization

```
require(["dojo/i18n!myapp/nls/extTools_i18nStrings"],function(extTools_i18nStrings){  
// Do something with the loaded file  
});
```

If the resource file (extTools_i18nStrings) has syntax error, it will be shown in `dojo.js`. How can I handle it in my code? 
Try catch block did not work.

Thanks in advance.

> Error: Script error .............dojo.js:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is you don't want to. The right thing to do is fix the bundle. This is the same as having errors in your application code, and you would not expect the code to 'handle' that.

But since i18n is an AMD plugin running as part of the loader (which is why you can't try/catch it), the error might be reported through the [AMD micro event API](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/loader/amd.html#id17), and you could use that to show a better error. I'm not sure how you 'handle' this syntax error other than showing an error.

If you can't control the quality of the bundles via some part of your development or build process you'd have to invent your own alternative to dojo/i18n and you probably don't want to go down that route for all of your bundles.